# How to fix access issue in my python script

Tags: python-2.7

I want global access for my variables passed and set in a function.

```
def parse_command_line_arg(properties_section_name, properties_file,log_file):  
    print("Entering parse_command_line_arg: ")
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse.add_argument("-s")
    parse.add_argument("-p")
    parse.add_argument("-l")
    args = parse.parse_args()
    properties_section_name=args.s
    properties_file=args.p
    log_file=args.l
    print("properties_section_name: " + properties_section_name + ". properties_file: " + properties_file + ".log_file: " + log_file)  

    try:
        does_log_file_exist=os.path.isfile(log_file)
        does_prop_file_exist=os.path.isfile(properties_file)
        if properties_section_name is None:
            raise Exception("Properties section name cannot be empty")
        if not does_log_file_exist :
            raise Exception("Log File " + log_file + " doesnot exist")
        if not does_prop_file_exist :
            raise Exception("Properties File " + properties_file + " doesnot exist")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise
    finally:
        print("Exiting function parse_command_line_arg")
```

I tried putting print statements and checked the variable names passed. With no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Main code in the same file:

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the post.

Comment: Not being able to access local variables from outside a function is intentional. You should probably **return** something from the function.

Comment: First check the indentation of your code... Lots of IndentationError

Comment: I am modifying the variables passed in the function @ mkrieger1. Also wouldnt want to return/ cannot afford to return so many variable values

Comment: @AkashMahapatra changed it already. Thanks

Comment: No indentation issue, in the code. Sorry all, actually I have been trying this for quite a long time. Part of my assigned task at office. So couldnt be careful about the indentation

Answer (score 0):

Adding global variables to function resolves the issue. But would like to know if this is a good coding practice?